# Can't see tray icon for Pidgin on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I can't see an icon for Pidgin in the tray when the app is running like I can with Windows.

I'm using Pidgin as I wanted one IM client for all OSes (OSX, Win7, Ubuntu).

How can I know if there is a new message without an icon? I have to keep checking the app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dconf key that stores the whitelist for Unity’s systray (the thing that shows the ugly green skype icon but doesn’t show your dropbox icon).

To see the current value type:

gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist

You should get something like:  ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Skype']

Now if you, like me, use the Skype plugin for Pidgin you don’t need Skype’s non-mono icon disrupting your dekstop, and if you would like to see what Dropbox is doing (at least I don’t see any indicator support for now…) you can change this key with this command:

gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Dropbox']"

And voila  no Skype icon but the dropbox icon is sitting in your tray after your the next login.”

Source - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-hide-or-show-app-tray-applets-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: I read that before posting... How do I find out what to 'set' as I tried Pidgin, but it didn't work. Also I have a dropbox icon by default :S